# Trying to extract information throught a PHP file Undefined

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to extract the information with a XHR request (AJAX) to a php file (this php file gets the information throught json file with Get request too) so when I try to do console.log(Checker) on the console, it returns Undefined and if I put alert(Checker) it returns [object Object]. How can I solve it?

PHP:

```
<?php
headers('Content-Type', 'application/json')
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('../data/data.json');
echo $jsonContents
?>
```

JS:

```
function start() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/domain/showall.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
            displayTheData(data)
    }
});
}

function displayTheData(data) {
    Checker = data;
    JSON.stringify(Checker)
    console.log(Checker)
    window.Checker = Checker;
}
```

JSON:

```
[{"name":"Google","url":"google.es","id":1}]
```

Comment: where you called `displayTheData()`? I didn't see any function calling code in your given source code.You have to call it inside `success`

Comment: Edited, but I returns "undefined"

Comment: `Edited`-> i didn't see any editing

Comment: Yeah it is edited

Comment: instead of `alert(data)` do `console.log(data);` and see any output is showing in your console or not? I yes then tell us that output

Comment: I changed it, and it didn't show nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are strigify data but not store value i any var.

```
function displayTheData(data) {
    Checker = data;
    var displayChecker = JSON.stringify(Checker) /// add  displayChecker  
    console.log(displayChecker )    // print it 
    window.Checker = Checker;
}
```

There is not displayTheData() function so first call it and pass response params.

Comment: It works!! Thanks you mate! @Akilesh Kumar You are right to

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the JSON Response ! Change return $jsonContents; to echo $jsonContents; it will work !!!

Answer (score 0):

You must parse data into body (not returning it which has no meaning outside a function) and, optionnaly but much better, fill some headers. A very minimalistic approach could be :

```
<?php
headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('../data/data.json');
echo $jsonContents // echo JSON string
?>
```

Comment: But I want do a request, if I put it into a body it won't be a request

Comment: The request is JS side. I'm talking of the body of the php response.

Comment: In an HTTP response, you have the headers (that tells what kind of response is) and the body that contains the payload itself. In your case : [{"name":"Google","url":"google.es","id":1}] that will be accessible in the data var of your JS script.

Comment: What are you calling PHP body ?

Comment: I'm trying to call PHP body

Comment: Have you checked the JSON file server side ? You can try echo $jsonContents; die; Your browser should display the string in window